# Linespread in titlepage with \huge

Tags: titles, line-spacing

What is the right way to increase the line height or spacing between lines in the `titlepage` environment when you have `\huge` titles?

I tried to increase it using the `\linespread` command but whatever value I give it, the two lines of the title remain too tight with each other, with a couple of letters `g` and `f` that happened to be underneath each other ending up touching each other.

**Update** Here is a sample of what I have in my `titlepage`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{times}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    { \huge \bfseries \linespread{2.0} This is a sample of a long title which I wish to get a little more line spacing for but linespread doesn't seem to work.}\\[0.4cm] 
    \HRule \\[1.5cm] 

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't expect others to reproduce your problem from scratch: please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: please always show a document that shows the problem. Although a guess: If you have text like `{\huge some text}` that is wrong, it should be `{\huge some text\par}` then will get a line spacing to match the font size.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle its not a duplicate of that, I already checked it. I am going to put a sample, but its as you're saying essentially.

Comment: The question is an exact duplicate, you should always include a paragraph end in the size change.

Comment: @Jubobs Added a MWE, sorry for omitting it originally.

Comment: The size change increases the baselineskip the linespread increases it more then the `}` ends the group and restores all the settings _then_ the paragraph ends and so is set with the original baselineskip you need to end the para within the group then you don't need all the `\\[..]` which is exactly the answer given in the duplicate question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, didn't get it. In the actual title there is no `\\. The `\\ in the beginning and in the end are because of that `\HRule`. What am I missing?

Comment: in your MWE you have `.}\\[0.4cm] ` that is wrong it should be `\par}` possibly followed by `\vspace{..}` if you need space

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK got it thanks for that. Can I reduce the spacing between title lines in some way? because now it is too much.

Comment: well remove the linespread if it is still there

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, no it wasn't in the title, but I had another one to do the rest of the document double line spaced. Thanks for your help. Some of us are newbies, so even though we try our best to find a solution without asking, its sometimes difficult to realise that its the same problem. Thanks for your help once again.